# How can I show that the dot product is a linear functional?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that the dot product is a linear functional?

If I am given a function I have to show that $w(ax_1+bx_2) = aw(x_1) + bw(x_2)$ for it to be a linear functional. I am having trouble seeing how this works for the dot product.

Comment: The dot product is *bi*linear, i.e., it becomes a linear functional once you fix one of its two arguments. Is this what you're trying to show?

Comment: Yes I believe that is what I am looking for Alex.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that $\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y$ is a linear functional. Rather, let $\mathbf x$ be a fixed vector in $\mathbb R$. Then the map $f(\mathbf y)=\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y$ is a linear functional.

Comment: Oh I see the definition in that statement now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For some transformation $\mathbf{T}:V \rightarrow W$ to be linear, it must fulfill

$$\mathbf{T}(v_1+v_2)=\mathbf{T}(v_1)+\mathbf{T}(v_2)$$
$$ \mathbf{T}(\lambda v) =\lambda\mathbf{T}(v)$$

for any vectors $v,v_1,v_2$ in $V$ and for any scalar $\lambda$. Do you know how to check this for the dot product?